# Solidity/Remix Error: The constructor should be payable if you send value enum change state

Tags: contract-design, design-patterns

I'm using [this](https://github.com/fravoll/solidity-patterns/blob/master/docs/state_machine.md) (State Machine) design pattern in solidity and having an error when changing the state after executing the first function. Any hint? Thank you!

> Error: revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
>   Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value.    Debug the
>   transaction to get more information.

Sorry I didn't include my sample code.

**Here's my sample code.**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract BankATM {

    enum Stages {
        ServingCustomer,
        Finished,
        Idle
    }

    address owner;

    mapping(address => uint256) balances;

    Stages public stage = Stages.ServingCustomer;

    constructor () payable public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier atStage(Stages _stage) {
        require(stage == _stage);
        _;
    }

    modifier transitionAfter() {
        _;
        nextStage();
    }

    modifier timedTransitions() {
        if (stage == Stages.ServingCustomer) {
            nextStage();
        }
        if (stage == Stages.Finished) {
            nextStage();
        }
        _;
    }

    function deposit(uint _amount) public payable timedTransitions atStage(Stages.ServingCustomer) {
        balances[msg.sender] += _amount;
    }

    function txFinished() public timedTransitions atStage(Stages.Finished) transitionAfter returns(uint) {
        return getBalance();
    }

    function idleNow() public view atStage(Stages.Idle) returns (uint) {
        return getBalance();
    }

    function getBalance() internal view returns (uint256){
        return balances[msg.sender];
    }

    function nextStage() internal {
        stage = Stages(uint(stage) + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are doing some mistake in function call. Are you calling the `bid` function after successful deployment of contract?

Comment: @A.K. Hi, I updated my post with my sample codes.

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
constructor() public payable{
}
```

When you create contract creation transaction

if send ETH together, need `payable` option in constrcutor